What is the translation of a feeler in French?
A feeler is a:

a tentative proposal intended to ascertain someone's attitude or opinion.

Example:

The hope is still that the fight is on. There is positivity, I'd say. But they have sent out feelers to see who might be able to fill in, either as a replacement or an entirely new fight at the top of the bill. Still developing, and still some time.

What is the translation of a feeler in French? Google translate suggests "sonde" and Linguee suggests "jauge" but both sounds a bit weird to me used as a noun in this context. E.g.,

ils ont envoyé des sondes pour voir qui pourrait le remplacer

sounds strange to me.

Les verbes sonder et jauger correspondent bien à ce sens, mais malheureusement, les substantifs sondage et jaugeage ne conviennent pas.

@XouDo je suis d'accord, je pense que le mieux est d'utiliser sonder ou jauger pour toute l'expression "to send a feeler", plutôt que d'essayer de traduire le nom.

As a tangentially related tidbit, the Scandinavian equivalent would be almost a mixture of sonder as mentioned in the comments and tâter le terrain as mentioned in the answer – e.g., in Danish, it would be sondere terrænet (‘sonder le terrain’).

I vote to close this question because beyond Google Translate and Linguee, proper online dictionaries like Larousse, Collins have perfectly serviceable entries for this meaning of feelers.

@guillaume31 I beg to differ: all I find proposed in those sources, like antenne, palpeur addresses the technical sense of the word, not the figurative. As a translation of "to send feelers", secouer ses antennes is quite exotic in its imagery.

@FrançoisJurain Collins: "to put out feelers: tâter le terrain". Larousse: to put out feelers (figurative) - tâter le terrain...

@guillaume31 but the question is: What is the translation of a feeler in French?

@FranckDernoncourt There is no such thing as "the translation of". There is a translation in a context and the dictionary entries I gave are a perfect match for "feeler" as used in the context of the article in your Q.

@guillaume31 they are indeed. Counting the comments though, I'll venture a number of us have been unable to find out these entries.

@guillaume31 I was trying to find a French noun expressing "a tentative proposal intended to ascertain someone's attitude or opinion.".

@FranckDernoncourt I think you should update your question to specify you're asking for a single noun and not an expression. Otherwise a typical answer will look for accuracy in meaning above grammatical closeness to the English version (which is, at least for the one in the article excerpt, also an expression btw : to send out feelers).

In the subfield of politics, when some measure is announced without having being voted (and is sometimes refuted or simply forgotten), it's common to talk about un ballon d'essai, which has been brought to English as a trial balloon (literal translation).

Rather than translating just feeler, I think it makes more sense to translate "to send out feelers".
From WordReference:

put out a feeler,
put a feeler out,
put out feelers,
put feelers out:
tâter le terrain

Tâter le terrain is very idiomatic and fits well here I think.

+1 for the suggestion to translate the full expression rather than the word. Let's note the variant : "prendre la température"

Here's one more argument against closing the question: I found a few attempts online to develop the French metaphor tâter le terrain along ethological lines, in likely parody of the English. These are obviously personal creations, not (yet?) clichés.

C'est l'amibe freudienne qui tend ses pseudopodes centrifuges prudents,

in De la guérison psychanalytique Chap. 2, Nathalie Zaltzman.

Juste question d'aller tâter de l'orteil la chaleur proverbiale française!,

in the reply by user lacstjean to the post le bain de prunelle on a French-speaking forum.
I found the 2nd quote among about 1/2-page of Google results for "tâter de l'orteil" in the proper sense: to dip a testing toe into water, sewage, mud or other liquid mass.
Cf. "envoyer un tentacule", which only brings back biographies of octopusses and science-fiction about tentacle-limbed aliens.
